# Disable caching of web-page doesn't consider background images

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser

Except when testing in another browser, most of the time I use Google Chrome while developing my web-app. I removed tag "Caching" in web-page developer menu, and it works with all CSS, except background image.

So if I change the background image, I need to open a new tab to see how it looks, because refreshing doesn't work here.

What do I need to do to stop Chrome from caching a web page's background image so that I can see any changes I might make without needing to load the page in a new tab.

Comment: -1: Spelling makes the question very hard to read.  In spite of this, when getting to the end, I'm still not sure what is being asked.  Can't answer a question if I have no idea what is being asked.  Also can't edit the question to clarify it for others.

Comment: Bro, English is not my native, and about subject - if you don't get what I'm talking about, that means that you are not into the topic.

Comment: What about ctrl-refresh?